# Why isn't this Metahuman in Iron Heights?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Supposedly in the beginning of Season 2 Iron Heights prison has a section meant to hold metahuman criminals (Cisco even contributed to the design) but Barry and Co, after taking down a thief and killer Cisco nicknamed 'Turtle', chose to lock him up in the Pipeline at STAR labs- wasn't setting up a metahuman wing at Iron Heights supposed to be an alternative to the pipeline, one that didn't ignore the meta's civil rights or whatnot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barry and Co needed to harness Turtle's powers to be able to show down Zoom. Locking him up in Iron Heights wouldn't have given them the access to him that they needed.

> Jay Garrick: Okay, so if we can catch him, figure out how he uses his powers...
>
> Cisco: Maybe we can show Zoom what life is like in the slow lane.